# Extra blank page occur in composite datawindow - Power Builder

Tags: powerbuilder

I have a composite dw where two reports are in detail band.
It will print out second report whenever there is any data related.
But for sure, first report will always be printed out.

I am currently having an issue with the first report.
If no data for second report, it prints only first report, however, there is an extra blank page.
When second report is print altogether, it is all good, no extra blank page.

I have checked it, it is all within margin.
If I print separately (meaning don't use composite dw), it will have no extra blank page for first and second report.

Also, for the second report in composite dw, it looks a bit weird. The height for second report should be exactly as the red boxes, but it print only half.

[Please check the image for composite dw preview report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8Xxv.png)

Any ideas on what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention which PowerBuilder version, but, composite datawindows have always been temperamental for me.

Some tips:

- What you see in the IDE is not necessarily what will print unless you use print preview. Print preview can be slightly different than what prints on printer especially PostScript printers that alias Arial as Helvetica.
- While the paper may be 8.5" x 11", your print driver may disagree. You may have to try a few things.
- Set the margins on the composite datawindow for your target printer.
- Change the margins on the report datawindows to be 0 top, bottom, left, and right. I set these at runtime for convenience.
- Don't forget groupcalc() after you insert rows or change something. Groupcalc report datawindows first then composite last.

---

This isn't a great solution but I suspect it will work.

If there is no data for the second report then insert a row into the second report.

You will need to

- composite.getchild( "secondreport", child )
- if child.rowcount() = 0 then child.insertrow( 0 ).
- You may then need to do a child.groupcalc()
- then composite.groupcalc()

Please let us know how you resolve your issue

Comment: Hi, Eric. First of all, thank you for your answer. FYI, I am using Power Builder 7.0. I tried to set the margin in composite dw to be 0, however, it still has extra blank page. The margin that I set before is for the printer that I am going to use for printing. FYI, the second solution works well. I can print my report without extra blank page. But as you said, it might not be a good solution. As getChild method is not available for nested report. And if I want to use this method, I have to change the report dw as it is a nested report as for now. Thank you so much

Comment: This is how I do it
First, I use getChild() method - DatawWindow.getChild("first_report", child).
Then, I do rowCount(). If the rowCount() is greater than 0, I will use getItemNumber(). In my first report dw, I have a computed field for pageCount().